# Read matrix data and its dimensions from file [C++]

Tags: c++, matrix

I have a txt file which is structured as follows:

```
<num Rows> <num Columns>
<M(0,0)> ... <M(0,nColumns-1)>
...
<M(nRows-1,0)> ... <M(nRows-1,nColumns-1)>
```

In other words the first line is just 2 scalars, namely the number of rows and columns in the matrix. From the second line, the matrix body starts.

I want to import such matrix in C++, following these steps:

1. Preallocation of a matrix with nRows rows and nColumns columns after reading the first line
2. Fill the matrix by reading the rest of the txt file.

I've been trying so far the following code:

```
har line[256];
int nRows; int nCols;
int i; int j;

bool FirstLine=true;
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fileIN)) {
    if (FirstLine==true){
        char nRowsC=line[0];
        nRows=nRowsC- '0';

        char nColsC=line[2];
        nCols=nColsC- '0';

        FirstLine=false;

        double **myMat=(double**)malloc(nRows*sizeof(double*));
        for(i=0; i<nRows; i++){
            myMat[i]=(double*)malloc(nCols*sizeof(double));
        }

        printf("Number of rows in data matrix: %d\n",nRows);
        printf("Number of columns in data matrix: %d\n\n",nCols);

        for(i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < nCols; j++)
            {
                if (!fscanf(fileIN, "%lf", &myMat[i][j]))
                    break;
                printf("(%d,%d) %lf\n",i,j,myMat[i][j]);
            }

        }
    }
}
cout << '\n'; cout << '\n'; cout << '\n';
for(i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < nCols; j++)
    {
        printf("(%d,%d) %lf\n",i,j,myMat[i][j]); //<-- this line gives the error
    }
}
```

And everything seems ok but if I print out such matrix I get an error that identifier "myMat" is undeclared (in particular: "Use of undeclared identifier 'myMat'". Compiler: XCode 7.2 on Mac OS X 10.11).

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]. Where did you actually define `myMat`?

Comment: Thats not c++, neither c. Choose one and don't mix them like this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, myMat is defined after "FirstLine=false;"

Comment: @tkausl. Just cout and printf are mixed up.

Comment: And malloc and char-array (c-string) and fgets and so on. Thats not c++. The only c++ part is cout, the rest is c.

Comment: Alright Your Highness, please forgive me if I usually code in Python and Matlab.

Comment: @tkausl: the question may be mixed language, but I doubt that this hinders answering int.

Comment: "_but if I print out such matrix I get an error that identifier "myMat" is undeclared_" - Post the exact error and where exactly you get it

Comment: @Galik, removed the 'c' tag and added line with error.

Comment: @SpookyKid: I totally agree with @Galik and @tkausl that _this is not at all_ idiomatic C++: whe try avoiding `new` and `malloc` at all cost.  You would probably benefit replacing `myMat` by a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`.

Answer (score 2):

You said it yourself: `myMat` is declared in... a scope that has already been closed.

Unlike Python, [C++ has block-scoping](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) rules:

```
double** myMat;
{
   int inner;
   myMat = foo(); // allowed: myMat is visible here
}
inner = 5; // compiler error: inner not visible anymore
```

If you want to access this variable, you should *declare* it in the outer scope, and fill it where you fill it now.

As a sidenote, C++ is evolving in a direction where we don't allocate much anymore in application code.  Your code will probably be a lot safer and more readable if you revert it to use `std::vector`:

```
using Row = std::vector<double>;
using Matrix = std::vector<Row>;

Matrix myMat;
```

see an example at http://cpp.sh/4iu4.

Comment: That's what I thought but...the while actually closes the scope?! That's ridiculous. Only inside the while body i know what is the value of nRows and nColumns

Comment: Your strong opinions hide the truth.  Accept that the language has been designed by smarter people than us, and go read up.

Comment: I do not want to argue, absolutely. These are the rules, stop. So I have to declare the matrix outside the while loop and that's ok, although just inside the loop I know what the values for nColumns and nRows. I can just close this loop, declare the matrix, reopen another loop that skips the first line of such matrix, am I right?

Comment: Sorted by declaring
'double **myMat;'
outside the while loop and removing it from inside the loop.

Comment: @SpookyKid You declare the variable outside like `double **myMat= NULL;`, and assign the result of `malloc()` inside the loop, that simple.

Comment: @xtofl Well buddy, ya know at that time the question was tagged `c` and using `malloc()`. Sure `nullptr` is correct c++.